# Rails How to easy show hide user fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want easy implement a show hide funktion on sertant fields. Like birthday or email for a user. Example if the user has chosen to hide his email it wont display in his profile.

How do i create this?

Best regards,

A Rails (3) beginner

Answer (score 2):

One option would be creating a model to store user preferences in to keep track of what the user wants to show/hide. Another option is to use one of the gems out there that will help you accomplish this task.
Just looking on github, I came across https://github.com/pluginaweek/preferences.

Comment: +1 for preferences (however I haven't used it before, but it seems as a good solution), but -1 for rails-settings - it is good in storing whole application settings, not a single object settings as it would be in this case. So it seems that I shouldn't upvote you ;) but I will

Comment: @klew good point! I guess it would be hard to use that with multiple user accounts. Going to edit the question to not mislead anyone.